# Sending SMS without showing Company name instead of Senders Number at the receiver

Tags: sms, message, messaging, at-command

How can i send SMS to the customers from my company name? that means instead of showing sender phone number at receiver as bellow.

Sender:+91XXXXXXXXXX 
Message: HI Friends

Some what like..

Sender:TM-ComName 
Message: HI Friends

Do I have to subscribe for this? Any where..
I would like to send SMS for new registration confirmation from my website

Comment: You need to contact network providers for that.

Comment: Can you clarify what means of sending the SMS message you are interested in? Are you talking just about your personal phone or are you relying on some SMS gateway?